# How to add logging table to Views?

Tags: drupal-views

I would like to add one of the logging tables to Drupal Views.  The list of CiviCRM tables that is provided does not include these tables. I've tried adding one in Drupal's settings.php but it doesn't appear in Views. For security & GDPR purposes it would be very useful to add these tables.  Can this be done and how?

Comment: would this help? https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2019-03-27/how-to-add-a-view-for-a-custom-table

Comment: Thanks, but for the first module it appears that the the custom table has to be in the Drupal database, and the second is for Drupal 8.